# How can I compare two attributes in a loop in Handlebars.js where one attribute is outside the loop scope?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars.js to display an element depending on whether a string matches the current user's username.

I'm actually looping through a collection `blogs` and this is where the attribute `author` comes into play. Regardless, `author.username` represents some username string and this is available to me. My problem is that if I change `user.attributes.username` to some pre-defined string, i.e. "martin" then the condition checks out and it displays the element the way I want. But I also have an attribute `user.attributes.username` and this renders just fine outside the `#ifEquals` condition. I really want to compare `author.username` with this attribute, and not some pre-defined string.

How can I compare two attributes, i.e. `author.username` with `user.attributes.username` instead of `author.username` with `"martin"`?

Both `author.username` and `user.attributes.username` have the same value. This doesn't work for me right now but is what I ultimately want:

```
{{#each blog}}
        {{#ifEquals author.username user.attributes.username}}
            <a href="#" onClick="return false;"><span class="delete-container" style="cursor: pointer" data-blog-id="{{objectId}}"><span class="typcn typcn-arrow-sorted-down hvr-pulse-grow" style="color: gray; font-size: 30px;"></span></span></a>
        {{/ifEquals}}
{{/each}}
```

This works but isn't sufficient for my purposes:

```
{{#each blog}}
        {{#ifEquals author.username "martin"}}
            <a href="#" onClick="return false;"><span class="delete-container" style="cursor: pointer" data-blog-id="{{objectId}}"><span class="typcn typcn-arrow-sorted-down hvr-pulse-grow" style="color: gray; font-size: 30px;"></span></span></a>
        {{/ifEquals}}
{{/each}}
```

**Handlebars.js Helper:**

```
<script>
    Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEquals', function(arg1, arg2, options) {
        return (arg1 == arg2) ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:** Upon further inspection, it looks like the problem is that `user.attributes.username` won't render inside the `blog` loop. It thinks `user` is an attribute of `blog`. Is there any way to access `user` as if it were outside the scope of the loop?

Comment: are you using `ember.js`?

Comment: No. Added the tag by accident. Thanks. Removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you can access outer-loop attributes in Handlebars.js by appending `../`

`{{currentUser.username}} // Renders fine outside the loop`

```
 {{#each blog}}
    // Append ../ to access currentUser inside the loop
    {{#ifEquals author.username ../currentUser.username}}
        // Show element here
    {{/ifEquals}}
 {{/each}}
```

`../user` is an attribute that comes from outside the `blog` loop, whereas `author` belongs to `blog`.